# How to share constants between projects?

Tags: c#, structure

I'm working on a C# console app that dumps data into a database, and an aspx / aspx.cs front end that reads that database to display the data.

Is there a neat way I can share the database table information between the two projects? Table name, column names etc?

Comment: create class in dll project, import this to each two projects?

Comment: Split the database/repository logic out in to a separate project. you can then include this in both solutions.

Comment: Agree with @phuzi. And if you separate it into a separate assembly, there is absolutely no reason not to "hardcode" the names of stored procedures and other database objects. Those things act essentially as variable names, and you don't store the names of variables as constants; you write them into source code. It's an extra layer of indirection that is not needed.

Comment: Sounds like what you are looking for is a shared configuration file. You could even use environment variables for this, depending on how portable you want this to be between different runtimes. At least I would recommend not to over-engineer this into some shared library or resource files ...

Comment: Is the idea to share the database between the 2 projects?

Comment: I'm a C# newbie (coming from C / C++) so some of these concepts are new to me! In C I'd just share a header file.  Having done more research, I'm creating a new assembly which I can use in both projects - this just contains a class with some constants. What you'r suggesting is probably better - the class should contain everything to read and write from the DB so both applications use the shared logic / constants... OK

Comment: @num-lock how is using resource files for the purpose for which they were designed "over-engineering"?

Comment: @NumLock Avoiding duplicate code is "clean-code" not "over-engineering".

Comment: @TomW This is not a use-case resource files were designed for, though.

Comment: @Fildor Point me to the statement I've given that says something about not avoiding duplicate code. I'm super excited to read about that. In the meantime read my comment again. Thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a project for the Data Access Layer

2) Include the project in both the other 2 projects

3) Use the classes you made

Comment: As I'm a C# newbie ... the Data Access Layer builds as a DLL which I include as a reference in my project. Does that make it a build time dependency only? There's no requirement to deploy an exe and the DLL when the system goes live?

Comment: Yes a DLL will be built with tthe exe

Comment: @craker no, the DLL must be physically present with the exe. To my knowledge the CLR doesn't support static linking, dependencies are always dynamically linked.

Answer (score 1):

You can hold those values in files which are set as [embedded resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-resource-files-for-desktop-apps), and then include the same files in more than one project. The Embedded Resource content type works for any file, but there is additional framework support for .resources files that make them easier to access at runtime.

You could also create another class library project just to hold those values, and include that project as a dependency of several projects. However creating an assembly just to hold a few constant values feels like a misuse to me.

Comment: Sharing some constants, only probably will lead to duplicate code in both projects. Which will in case of changes lead to the need of identical change in two projects. So why not only extract the constants but also the duplicate code in the shared project? You could even make a "private/local" nuget and have it versioned and everything.

Comment: @Fildor I suppose so, and I concede I didn't read the intent of the question closely enough, saw "database" and assumed connection strings. You're correct that if this really does concern a data access layer then yes, a shared assembly implementing this functionality (unit of work? query objects?) would be a better choice.